# BeautifulSoup not showing all contents of html page

Tags: python, html

I am trying to parse through the page http://www.omaharealtors.com/market-stats to pull out a link, but I can't seem to figure out why when I use BeautifulSoup on this page, it won't show anything under the

```
<div id="SITE_CONTAINER"></div>
```

This is where all the contents are on the page, I have checked in Chrome to look at it. What I have so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.omaharealtors.com/market-stats').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
```

When I print soup to look at it, I see that `<div id="SITE_CONTAINER"></div>`, but then I can't get anything from within that. I have used this same method of opening other pages and have had no issues before, and I have even tried using `soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')` to see if that would make a difference, but no luck.
If anyone has any ideas on what could be causing this, or has any suggestions, that would be great.

Comment: this page use JavaScript/AJAX to add elements - BS doesn't run JavaScript. You need Selenium or you have to find url which JavaScript use to get data and use it.

Comment: And, as you mentioned, if you look at the source code SITE_CONTAINER div is empty. So, it's expected that you don't get anything back from that.

Comment: @Ulas Keles Well if you look at the source code in chrome you can see all of the contents of the page in the SITE_CONTAINER div, it is not empty. BeautifulSoup is just returning it as empty.

Comment: It is only "<div id="SITE_CONTAINER"></div>" if you do "View Page Source" which is similar to what happens when you get it through requests api. Though, if the page is already loaded and you inspect it, it does show you the populated div. In any case, you could use Selenium as suggested before, or take a look at dryscape module, it may also help.